# How to save open tabs to a single Favourites folder in IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have one IE 9 window open with 8 tabs in a specific order that is convenient for me to use so I want to save them in the order they are open to a single Favourites folder so I can load them using the "open all tabs together" thingy later.  Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?  Any suggestions?  I'm in the process of grouping sites in a specific tab order to help ease my workflow so I want to be able to save the tab order that worked well one day for the next day.

IE 9.
Win 7 Pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press **Alt** + **A** to open the Favorites menu, then select "Add current tabs to favorites...". You'll be able to create a new folder for the tabs.

To open them, open the Favorites pane, find the new folder, right-click on it and select "Open in tab group".

As long as you don't sort your favorites by name, they should remain in the same order as you originally opened them.